# How can I have my text fields be initialized without requiring user interaction?

Tags: flutter

I have the following flutter widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExperienceDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  const ExperienceDetails({super.key});

  @override
  State<ExperienceDetails> createState() => _ExperienceDetailsState();
}

class _ExperienceDetailsState extends State<ExperienceDetails> {
  List<ExperienceDetails> experiences = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: const Text(
          "Experience",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: experiences.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        ),
                        child: Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                          child: Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Experience ${index + 1}',
                                style: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                              const Spacer(),
                              IconButton(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    experiences.removeAt(index);
                                  });
                                },
                                icon: const Icon(Icons.delete),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 15),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          labelText: 'Company Name',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          labelText: 'Job Title',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          labelText: 'Duration',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                      TextField(
                        maxLines: null,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                          labelText: 'Details',
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  setState(() {
                    experiences.add(const ExperienceDetails());
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Add Experience'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I expected that when I entered the "Experience" screen, the text fields would be shown without having to click the "add" button first.

**Here is how I want the "Experience" screen to appear upon entry:**
[image]

**And here is what I actually get:**
[image]

I don't want the user to have to click the "add" button in order to reveal the text fields: they should start out visible without requiring any additional user interaction once the "Experience" screen loads.

How can I cause the text fields to be initialized upon the screen loading, without requiring a button press event?

Answer (score 1):

Every time you click the Elevated Button you add the whole class ExperienceDetails to your list. This class is basically the parent of your state class. This is not the right approach. Use a state management approach where your list state is modifiable in a proper way holding the entity experience details (which is a separate class).
Of course you not seeing any item, as your list is empty in first place. You could add at least one item in your init() method, but you still should use a state management approach.